# How to read file from storage in android?

Tags: java, android, file, uri

I'm saving an **excel** file to **storage** of device (**Android** **7**) , now i want to when user click on button the excel file be opened but now when button is clicked app going to crash while when im going to my storage and im opening file directly outside my app there is no problem !! please help if im wrong in any lines of code , thanks

> Log :  android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MessangerApp/MessangerDocuments/139703251134.xlsx
>   exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
>           at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed
>
> Directory of file : internal storage > MessangerApp >
>   MessangerDoucments >Test.xlsx

here my Code :

```
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + Config.DOC_DIRECTORY_Name + filename);
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            view.getContext().startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Android N, in order to work around this issue, you need to use the FileProvider API.

```
<manifest ...>
<application ...>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Create XML file res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

To open file in external office app

```
File excelFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"nameexcelFile.pdf");//File path
        if (excelFile.exists()) //Checking if the file exists or not
        {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(excelFile);
            Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            objIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(objIntent);//Starting the excel file viewer
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The file not exists! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: i want to when the button clicked list of program shows and choose office excel to open it , but the result of your codes is show content in provider_paths layout am i right ?

Comment: to use the external app you have to access file path first,
i updated my answer , check again

Comment: im added your last updated code , at the first the list of programms show but i couldnt find office excel so i add                 objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
 this code the result has prevoius Error that is write in my post